# Embedding HTML5 video for Mobile Safari on an iPhone 3GS vs an iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, html, video, h.264

I have an H.264/AAC encoded video in an mp4 file on the server, the mime-type video/mp4 is added to the web server (IIS 7), and I have a page with a video tag:

```
<video id="html5-video" width="360" height="202" poster="/images/poster.png" controls>
    <source src="/video/Web-360x202-14MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Works great on an iPhone 4, but on an iPhone 3GS (same iOS version, 4.3.2) is only shows the poster image and tapping it doesn't start the video.

When I try to open the video file directly, I get a 'tip' from the Mobile Safari developer console:

> Other Tip
>
> QuickTime
>
> Movie could not be played

What is needed to get HTML5 video working on an iPhone 3GS? Is it an encoding issue?

Comment: Can 3GS play this video if you sync it to the 3GS via iTunes?

Comment: I haven't tried, no iTunes at work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experienced the same issue and yes it seems that it's an encoding issue. I followed the Universal Smartphone profile provided here :

> Defaults:
>
> Video: H.264, Level 3.0, Baseline profile Audio: AAC, 1-2 channels
>
> Plays on:
>
> iOS: iPhone, iPad, Apple TV, iPod Touch, iPod Classic, iPod 5.5G
>   Blackberry: Bold 9000, Curve 8910, 8900, 8520, Pearl 9XXX, Storm,
>   Storm 2, Torch, Tour, Bold 9650 + 9700 Android: All (?) Other: PSP
>   (3.30+), PS3, Xbox 360, web
>
> Doesn’t play on:
>
> iPod 5G, PSP (pre-3.30), Blackberry Curve 9330, 9300, 8530, 83XX,
>   Pearl 8XXX, 88XX
>
> Settings:
>
> Defaults, plus:
>
> audio_bitrate: 128 (or less) audio_sample_rate: 44100 (or less) size:
>   480×320 max_frame_rate: 30 video_bitrate: 1500 (or less)

http://blog.zencoder.com/2010/09/30/how-to-encode-video-for-mobile-use/

and it solved the problem. My mp4 file can now be read both on iPhone 3gs and 4.

Comment: I was having the same problem, but it was my htaccess security. I'll make an answer.

Comment: Also, for the 3GS, you need to encode with the Baseline@3.0 or Baseline@3.1 codec profile.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this symbol

[image]

for your HTML `<video>` element on an iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4 it's because those phones will **only** play HTML videos if:

- There is a `<source>` that is a MP4 encoded with MPEG-4 H.264 Video Level 3 Baseline Profile + AAC Audio
- The resolution does not exceed the limit for the particular phone (see specs below)

I tried the iPhone profile on Miro Video Converter and it didn't work. The easiest transcoder I've found that will convert to this format is [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/).  Just transcode using the *iPod* preset for 3GS support and *iPhone & iPod* preset for iPod 4+ support with higher resolution.

**iPhone 4 specs from Apple**:

> Video formats supported: H.264 video up to 720p, 30 frames per second,
>   Main Profile level 3.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo
>   audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5
>   Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with
>   AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v,
>   .mp4, and .mov file formats; Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps, 1280
>   by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio
>   in .avi file format

https://support.apple.com/kb/SP587?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

**iPhone 3GS specs from Apple**:

> Video formats supported: H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480
>   pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264
>   Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio
>   in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; H.264 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640
>   by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 3.0
>   with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in
>   .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640
>   by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio
>   up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file
>   formats Support for 576p and 480p with Apple Component AV Cable; 576i
>   and 480i with Apple Composite AV Cable (cables sold separately)

https://support.apple.com/kb/SP565?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue but all these fixes weren't working. What did work eventually was to remove the htaccess protection I was using for those files. The previous answer is right, but this will fix any htaccess security problems.

```
AuthName "myusername"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /Library/WebServer/.htpasswd

Require valid-user

<FilesMatch mp3>
Satisfy any 
order allow,deny 
allow from all 
</FilesMatch> 

<FilesMatch mp4>
Satisfy any
order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch aac>
Satisfy any
order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch m4v>
Satisfy any
order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch m4b>
Satisfy any
order allow,deny
allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```