# How to encode video for Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, html, mobile, video, safari

I've been trying to encode a video trailer for mobile Safari playback (iPhone). Using Handbrake for Windows, I selected the source .mov file and chose the iPhone 4 preset. I then checked off the Web optimized option and started the process.

The resulting video did not play on my iPhone's Safari browser, however.

http://mobilevideo.jt.citeeze.com/static/trailer.m4v

If anyone has had success encoding mobile safari video with ffmpeg, could you provide the exact parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: You can refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5722505/1979005) for a couple of potential solutions, hope they help!!

Comment: i can't open it with chrome on mac too, and i think this question is not appropriate to be here because is not a development question.
or you can give us more details or some code.

Comment: Thanks guys. Thanks for the quick feedback. The tool is pretty straight forward. It's handbrake for windows and it comes pre-configured with defaults; I've tried those other answers but they don't seem to help;